# Alexa is 'Unable to Reach the Requested Skill'

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, ssh, alexa-skills-kit, ssh-tunnel

I'm receiving "I'm unable to reach the requested skill" message from an Alexa dashboard testing console for the skill that used to work before (with no modifications to any underlying infrastructure or code).

[image]

Here's the error obtained from Alexa's device logs:

```
{
"header": {
    "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
    "name": "CaptureError",
    "messageId": "57d00be6-19d6-4529-b0b1-4c5d6c2760ac"
},
"payload": {
    "skillId": "amzn1.ask.skill.db1bac88-183d-409c-9d3e-0e69fa0f5fe2",
    "timestamp": "2018-09-27T19:11:51.066Z",
    "dialogRequestId": "d9ec106d-2ef2-4526-a156-f4714ce5d034",
    "skillRequestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.1e166266-56e1-4c51-b40a-3ceb144f997f",
    "code": "SKILL_ENDPOINT_ERROR",
    "description": "An error occurred while issuing a SpeechletRequest for  (requestId [amzn1.echo-api.request.1e166266-56e1-4c51-b40a-3ceb144f997f]",
    "debuggingInfo": {
        "type": "SkillExecutionInfo",
        "content": {
            "invocationRequest": {
                "endpoint": "https://emptio.serveo.net/abc/api/v1/alexa",
                "body": {
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "session": {
                        "new": false,
                        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.bfc02d53-fe83-4c70-b731-ea7ede99d20a",
                        "application": {
                            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.db1bac88-183d-409c-9d3e-0e69fa0f5fe2"
                        },
                        "user": {
                            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGX2NO3NXXDS6NLEZMDZXMRZZPJ3DLEERYK7J3NUPFUYRADFB2HRILB7BZVTN336OFVSNFFUP3VDVFHERK5PKQE5H32EQ5GGWTT67EMDQKP22Q7NTXXNYDUTYNCYI6EJUEODQ54VHKW4JSWVCS7JINWLYH2LICQVETFGZBY6NBDJVEX66VCGCZMRTFZYAG2E3IXDPMPVF3U4VMY",
                            "accessToken": "Atza|IwEBIM_YZylf-iVoydW0WhXTS4ykk6oA0FwI9Aa7Pdz_pysLPaL1AJwQLXA-Y1GJabHTWMJxfDEKyIiLFuxEPnTxuYaEDyany7WXzHMOd0-iiD9lYBxE6rIXkC3Z-I5PYU6DQtkT6DHxbusrkyGTb1bSfbznIaaFat3yNvKY9mXaNHEEhuuPRZJkXjffBA9WKzWrkGetOdHVvo-PLw2w9rWUiQQuJ6ryzQjugYILyCuTry3qz8lvqWGxYX0XB3dx_CGuzjEnNP0-X2ozhLXN8cBjtBrl7MlTffNyo6K94vi24-16bdIdFZG3mVL_bKSCXzAx2qzPJvBCn953FrPVw9zd7CtOintRSBDZ9Aw_QgKqTklliWTBP_8uRqq_nuMB8s992-Yhi6Zb-k7VvyYp7oLtJ8ggRqRlRk9vS4HBxyfKCxvfXmvlmZJlAtGjec_-Bx8UB2pf1ZH0xi-2LYpezVh2e7dgWenKU0PHvtduprVtpO4E72148mddcYyQRzAEdk8LYQx1SiamYY64_qmkv14h1qBPUIQPuv3MFt2PB7Mhm6cVTA"
                        }
                    },
                    "context": {
                        "System": {
                            "application": {
                                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.db1bac88-183d-409c-9d3e-0e69fa0f5fe2"
                            },
                            "user": {
                                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AGX2NO3NXXDS6NLEZMDZXMRZZPJ3DLEERYK7J3NUPFUYRADFB2HRILB7BZVTN336OFVSNFFUP3VDVFHERK5PKQE5H32EQ5GGWTT67EMDQKP22Q7NTXXNYDUTYNCYI6EJUEODQ54VHKW4JSWVCS7JINWLYH2LICQVETFGZBY6NBDJVEX66VCGCZMRTFZYAG2E3IXDPMPVF3U4VMY",
                                "accessToken": "Atza|IwEBIM_YZylf-iVoydW0WhXTS4ykk6oA0FwI9Aa7Pdz_pysLPaL1AJwQLXA-Y1GJabHTWMJxfDEKyIiLFuxEPnTxuYaEDyany7WXzHMOd0-iiD9lYBxE6rIXkC3Z-I5PYU6DQtkT6DHxbusrkyGTb1bSfbznIaaFat3yNvKY9mXaNHEEhuuPRZJkXjffBA9WKzWrkGetOdHVvo-PLw2w9rWUiQQuJ6ryzQjugYILyCuTry3qz8lvqWGxYX0XB3dx_CGuzjEnNP0-X2ozhLXN8cBjtBrl7MlTffNyo6K94vi24-16bdIdFZG3mVL_bKSCXzAx2qzPJvBCn953FrPVw9zd7CtOintRSBDZ9Aw_QgKqTklliWTBP_8uRqq_nuMB8s992-Yhi6Zb-k7VvyYp7oLtJ8ggRqRlRk9vS4HBxyfKCxvfXmvlmZJlAtGjec_-Bx8UB2pf1ZH0xi-2LYpezVh2e7dgWenKU0PHvtduprVtpO4E72148mddcYyQRzAEdk8LYQx1SiamYY64_qmkv14h1qBPUIQPuv3MFt2PB7Mhm6cVTA"
                            },
                            "device": {
                                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AGUTTO7VCXPCUUSXNDCNO6LK7LZHUKPDGZBOXUOBNRNOBGD7FHBJWHOK3LJNQX4U47HTFLUXJ6MHBL6V7UCDNTWOMBJIP5R4R2ZVK3XJX42PEZG6J6TCS3U7NSYZZ3PDCUSH22CY7LYGNIK2MGXCUGR4ITQQ",
                                "supportedInterfaces": {}
                            },
                            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
                            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.LzPCt8QPxkEa5jFK3IMGMQLWS3vXOopyGKBu0cAy1cnJzAk7wnbKwc9eyQYDMr3uH7MyHr4s7xUKpWlvspGOAL3LqKxFbxqpB5zIjhKifqdGQhB_nurOAjeyZOipZ0ZhSuPN9fqTwp7zwca4LdYz6Kuahklz7D7pU7ICNI1DNqNKDx9HmyWbJIwXWL3MvS9sEujDo15oTdiueNaCbC7kLnPi0adrukHy3J6HVN_XjWS5mSSawuObgiT2b9eLm4qntoMG7MnDTSrzxmhKgXm3WrbFxRW_ZKE3uu1wa7-412f8DPxvbVZkeYDRwWMTO8s7BtnzjPcKEcT6daLXKRgpVw"
                        }
                    },
                    "request": {
                        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
                        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.1e166266-56e1-4c51-b40a-3ceb144f997f",
                        "timestamp": "2018-09-27T19:11:47Z",
                        "locale": "en-US",
                        "reason": "ERROR",
                        "error": {
                            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
                            "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "invocationResponse": null,
            "metrics": {
                "skillExecutionTimeInMilliseconds": 3107
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

As is seen from the above response, the skill is configured with an endpoint: `https://emptio.serveo.net/abc/api/v1/alexa` which is perfectly reachable.

Again, the same exact skill used to work just yesterday.  The invocation name under which I am calling it used to work fine.

I'm able to reach and verify the above endpoint is functional and responsive outside Alexa, but it's somehow not reachable from the Alexa dashboard.

I'm monitoring the logs from Serveo - they don't show any activity, meaning that something is broken before the webhook is called.

What could be the reason for the error?  How can I debug what is going on in the Alexa stack?

Comment: Are you using https endpoint for your backend ?? or AWS lambda function ?

Comment: I'm using a web service via secure endpoint

Comment: Does your web service fulfills all the requirements mentioned here :https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html

Comment: Yes, else it wouldn't have worked, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure option for the endpoint's SSL certificate type is correct. You can change this in the endpoint option in the web development console.

Your host might be using a wildcard certificate so select the wildcard option, save your endpoint again - then test again using the console for reachability.